# Error while building binutils 2.21.1a on Solaris

Tags: solaris, gnu, binutils, build-error

I'm trying to build binutils 2.21.1a from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils on Solaris sun4u sparc SunOS 5.10. I am using gcc version 4.0.2. When I built this is the error:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
compress.c: In function 'bfd_compress_section_contents':
compress.c:100: warning: implicit declaration of function 'compressBound'
make[2]: *** [compress.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nfs/netapp0/user/home/hart/downloads/binutils-2.21.1/bfd'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs/netapp0/user/home/hart/downloads/binutils-2.21.1/bfd'
*** Error code 2
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
```

I added the `--disable-werror` to the configure line to try to bypass it and hopefully continue the build.  Unfortunately this did not work either and I got this new, related, error at link time:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
compressBound                       ../bfd/.libs/libbfd.a(compress.o)
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to size
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have searched for an existing issue but I have found nothing related.  Any ideas?  I prefer to use this version of binutils, but if you know of a version that builds OK on this platform with gcc 4.0.2 specifically please let me know.

Comment: What says `grep compressBound /usr/include/zlib.h` ?

Comment: @jilliagre, I've already found the answer, see my answer below.  But yeah, the version of zlib on the system is too old for what is required by binutils and there is a bug in the auto configure script that doesn't appropriately check for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the issue was indeed filed as a [BUG](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12263).  The workaround is to add `--without-zlib` to the configure script or install an up to date version of zlib on the system.